# In MS Edge the Model does not change when selecting an option

Tags: angular, html-select, microsoft-edge

I have two issues with an HTML select element in Edge when used with Angular 2:

1. the default selection is the last added option using *ngFor
2. when select option the model does not get updated with the new selected option.

please check this Plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/MdNOlv?p=preview

```
 //our root app component
    import {Component, Directive, Output, EventEmitter, Input, SimpleChange} `from 'angular2/core'`
    import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import {Observer} from 'rxjs/Observer';

//import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template:`
    <h1>Selecting Number</h1>
    <select type="number" [(ngModel)]="levelNum" (ngModelChange)="toNumber()">
      <option *ngFor="#level of levels" [ngValue]="level.num">{{level.name}}</option>
    </select>
    {{levelNum}}
  `,
})
export class App {
  levelNum:number;
  levels:Array<Object> = [
      {num: 0, name: "AA"},
      {num: 1, name: "BB"}
  ];

  toNumber(){
    this.levelNum = +this.levelNum;
    console.log(this.levelNum);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this was fixed in beta.16. What version are you using?

Comment: I am using  2.0.0-beta.13 . I will update and check thank you

Comment: problem solved after update to beta 16 . Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved after updating Angular to Beta 16.